# Свойство products не существует в типе News

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Помогите исправить проблему, свойство `products` не существует в типе *News*

```
class News extends React.Component<{INewProps}, {}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.products = getProducts();
    this.state = {
      data: this.products
    };
  }

  public onDeleteRow(row) {
    this.products = this.products.filter((product) => {
      return product.id !== row[0];
    });

    this.setState({
      data: this.products,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте объявить products вне конструктора, а как поле класса

```
products = getProducts();
```

Answer (score 0):

Это из-за области видимости. Либо метод через bind привязывал, либо просто юзай arrow function.